# Ionic : Side Menu in tabs (lazy loading issue ?)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I’m actually struggling with an issue.
I have an ion-tabs who contain this tab :

```
      <ion-tab-button tab="plus" (click)="toggleMenu()">
        <ion-label>Plus</ion-label>
        <ion-icon name="ellipsis-horizontal"></ion-icon>
      </ion-tab-button>
```

I used before the ion-menu-toggle but its working better with a function reacting on the click of this button.
This part of code is include in my tabs page.

I have another page for my side menu.
i’m using simply an ion-menu with ion-content and différent ion-menu-toggle.
Everything is working fine.

But when I’m charging my app for the first time and I haven’t press the plus tabs yet, it didn’t open the menu.
Firstly it goes to the ‘plus’ page (who contains my menu).
It opens the page, I put an ion-content where I wrotte ‘menu’ to see if it goes to this page and it does.
If i’m pressing the plus tabs again it opens my menu then.
And when I leave to another tab and I come back to this one later it works perfectly.
It’s just not working for the first time.

So it’s not totally great for user experience, because if you want to open this tab (the menu) for the first time, it seems like it doesn’t work, you have to press one more time to makes it work.
Secondly I suppose I should keep my actual page when i want to open the side menu, and not going to the plus page.
But it’s okay if I keep another page for the menu, i can replace the actual code of the page who contain ‘menu’ by something else later like a picture.

This is the code of plus (menu) page :

```
<ion-header>
    <app-toolbar></app-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
    Menu
</ion-content>
<ion-app>
    <ion-menu side="end">
        <ion-header>
            <ion-toolbar>
                <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
            </ion-toolbar>
        </ion-header>
        <h1 class="ion-text-center">Menu</h1>
        <ion-content>
            <ion-list>
                <ion-menu-toggle>
                <ion-item lines="none" routerLink="/tabs/plus/game">
                    <ion-icon name="trophy" slot="start"></ion-icon>
                    <ion-label>Jeux Concours</ion-label>
                </ion-item>
                </ion-menu-toggle>
                <ion-menu-toggle>
                    <ion-item lines="none" routerLink="/tabs/plus/tickets" >
          <ion-icon name="pricetag" slot="start"></ion-icon>
                <ion-label>Billeterie</ion-label>
                </ion-item>
                </ion-menu-toggle>
                <ion-menu-toggle>
                    <ion-item lines="none" routerLink="/tabs/plus/social" >
          <ion-icon name="logo-facebook" slot="start"></ion-icon>
                <ion-label>Réseaux Sociaux</ion-label>
                </ion-item>
                </ion-menu-toggle>
                <ion-menu-toggle>
                    <ion-item lines="none" routerLink="/tabs/plus/news">
                    <ion-icon name="newspaper" slot="start"></ion-icon>
                    <ion-label>Actualités</ion-label>
                </ion-item>
                </ion-menu-toggle>
                <ion-menu-toggle>
                    <ion-item lines="none" routerLink="/tabs/plus/gallery">
                    <ion-icon name="images" slot="start"></ion-icon>
                    <ion-label>Galerie Photos</ion-label>
                </ion-item>
                </ion-menu-toggle>
                <ion-menu-toggle>
                    <ion-item lines="none" routerLink="/tabs/plus/settings">
                    <ion-icon name="settings" slot="start"></ion-icon>
                    <ion-label>Paramètres</ion-label>
                </ion-item>
                </ion-menu-toggle>
            </ion-list>
            <!--logo-->
            <div class="ion-text-center" style="margin-top: 5vh">
                <img src="../../assets/logo/logobleu.png"/>
            </div>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-menu>
    <ion-router-outlet main></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-app>
```

Thanks in advance, if someone actually had this kind of problems…
I’m using Ionic V5 with Angular.